# EXT3 vs EXT4 vs XFS

Tags: filesystems, ext3, ext4, xfs

Recently I read a lot about "new" file systems.

I checked some benchmarks that show MySQL working faster on EXT4 or XFS (and some other FS).

I also "found" that XFS and EXT4 are included in CentOS 5.X

However most of the articles I read speaks either very positively either very negatively on XFS. Same for EXT4.

Despite I have some Debian's that work on EXT4, I do not have experience with it.

Questions are - Is it safe?

If power stops - what will happen and what data could be lost?

If system crashes what will happen and what data could be lost?

If memory or some hardware (not the HDD controller or HDD) broke - what will happen and what data could be lost...

Answer (score 3):

*** sigh * - this has been done to death on this site, please try to search for previously-asked questions before duplicating them, but yes, anything like a filesystem that's not only included in a mainstream released distribution such as RHEL but actually the default is clearly safe yes.

As for your questions - in the event of a power loss or system crash transactional filesystems wind back non-committed writes to preserve coherence. As far as memory or other hardware crashing it depends on your hardware and the support for that failed component, there's not one answer across the board.

Comment: If "this has been done to death on this site", can someone please link to the duplicate questions so they appear under **Linked** in the sidebar?  Also, please remember that Jeff and Joel have said it's fine to ask the same question in a slightly different way so people can find it.  The title of this question ("ext3 vs. ext4 vs. xfs") sounded like what I was looking for.  I'll try to help by linking to http://serverfault.com/q/206772/1156 and http://serverfault.com/q/91734/1156

Comment: When you type in the title of a new question you are presented with a list of likely similar question titles below called "Questions that may already have your answer" - they're there for a reason.