# SLES 11 recommended filesystem

Tags: ext3, ext4, xfs, btrfs, sles11

We are upgrading some servers from SLES 10 to SLES 11 and I just saw that ext4 is not supported. Should I move to XFS or keep ext3?

I will be moving the programs and databases to a new VM so reformatting is not a problem. We are currently using ext3, but the fsck after a crash or the regular filesystem checks are very slow. I was thinking that ext4 would be supported under SLES 11 as it has a much faster fsck, but it's not. Btrfs doesn't seem production ready yet.

So now I'm thinking about moving to xfs, but I'm not sure it's as stable as ext3? I saw some old reports about truncating files wiht 0, but apparently those bugs are already closed.

The disks have a bunch of large database files, so xfs seems perfect for this scenario.

Comment: Have you thought about moving your DB data files to raw devices?

Comment: The software we are using doesn't support raw devices. I've formatted the data disk with xfs and it is working reliably. This is on enterprise hardware with bbu drives and ups so that may help, but so far I'm happy with xfs.

Answer (score 2):

I just saw a similar question:
[It is XFS reliable? In case of a power gone off is xfs riskier that ext3 in data corruption/safey?](https://serverfault.com/questions/206772/it-is-xfs-reliable-in-case-of-a-power-gone-off-is-xfs-riskier-that-ext3-in-data)

I don't know if things have changed, but it seems I'll stick with ext3.

Comment: That link is over three years old - that is a full live-cycle...